# validate custom method with jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate my form so as I can not type into the input bellow the code if it already exists into the list.

```
<input id="form:inptCode" type="text" name="form:inptCode" class="number">
```

Bellow is the html of the primefaces orderlist element.

```
<select id="form:choices_values" name="form:choices_values" multiple="true" class="ui-helper-hidden">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
</select>
```

So, the list contains the value 1. If I type the number 1 into the inputText, the error message should appear.

In order to achieve this I added a method and I tried to validate the form when this method returns false. 
I do not have much experience using jQuery validation, actually I wrote just a few methods.

```
$.validator.addMethod('codExistss', function (value, element) {
   var lstChoices = document.getElementById('form:choices_values');
   for (i = 0; i &lt; lstChoices.options.length; i++) {
        return value === lstChoices.option[i].value;
   }
}, "The code already exists.");

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#form').validate({
     rules: {
         'form:inptCode': {
              codExistss: false
         }
     }
  });
});
```

It seems that my code does not work. So, can you help me to understand why?

Comment: Change "&lt;" to <.

Comment: I just wrote the wrong name here, but in my page it is correct and the method is not working.

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: No, my console doesn't show any error. If i change &lt; with < I would have the error: "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.", because my page is xthml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a loop over all the list options:

```
  for (i = 0; i &lt; lstChoices.options.length; i++) {
        return value === lstChoices.option[i].value;
   }
```

assuming you will have more than 1 option, it's enough that only 1 time the condition will return true and your validation is ruined.

The second things is that you didn't turn on the rule flag for your custom function:
You had `codExistss: false`which mean "don't validate the input by this rule", change it to true.

Try this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('codExistss', function (value, element) {

       var lstChoices = document.getElementById('form:choices_values');
       if(lstChoices.options[lstChoices.selectedIndex].value===value) {return false;}
       return true;
       },"The code already exists.");

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#form').validate({
     rules: {
         'form:inptCode': {
    // Specify that form:inptCodeshould be validated
    // by codExistss rule
              codExistss: true
         }
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: My field should be valid only if the method returns false. If I specify codExistss: true how could it be validated when the codExistss return false?

Comment: No, your field is valid only if the function returns TRUE, if it returns FALSE it's not valid.

Comment: @NellyJunior, from how it looks like, you want to compare with the selected value from the select drop down, I edited the code, take a look.

Comment: You are right. I just changed the return condition. and  codexistss: true.
                       
                            if (value === lstChoices.options[i].value) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            else {
                                return true;
                            }

Comment: Thank, you. I would like to accept your answer, so could you adapt it to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I can save anyone Hours of Pain, I hope this helps!

I wanted a Required if, but for only a Single Method: Create, but not necessarily for Edit. Custom Validation.

My Model Property is like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// The HttpPostedFileBase for Uploading Images.
/// </summary>
[NotMapped]
[Display(Name = "Image")]
[RequiredIf("Create", ErrorMessage = "The Image field is required.")]
public HttpPostedFileBase DisplayImage { get; set; }
```

Here is the Custom RequiredIf Attribute class:

```
/// <summary>
/// A Custom Required If Attribute
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{



    #region Fields:



    #endregion



    #region Properties:



    private string Action { get; set; }



    #endregion



    public RequiredIfAttribute(object action)
    {

        Action = action.ToString();
    }



    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        string action = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

        // If Action == Create and the Image is NOT Null:
        if ((Action.Equals(action)) && (value != null))
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else 
        // If Action == Edit and Image is Null:
        if((!Action.Equals(action)) && (value == null))
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else
            // Return Error Message:
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

I have used Server Side Validation, so no Javascript/JQuery required, for simplicity as much as anything else.

Here is a snippet of my Controller:

```
/// <summary>
/// POST: /Create
/// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
/// more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="myModelViewModels"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "My Binding Attributes")] MyModelViewModels myModelViewModels)
{

    // If the Validation has failed, then the Model State will be Invalid!
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    // Do all the funky coding in here...

    }

    // Return the InValid Model here:
    return View(MyModelViewModels);
}
```

This is a little bit two step, the Model has to be return to the Client before the Clients knows a Requirement has or has not been met! JQuery would be nice to implement, for Client Side Validation!